# Simple Scala syntax - trying to define "==" operator - what am I missing?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

While experimenting with some stuff on the REPL, I got to a point where I needed something like this:

```
scala> class A(x:Int) { println(x); def ==(a:A) : Boolean = { this.x == a.x; } }
```

Just a simple class with an "==" operator.

Why doesn't it work???

Here's the result:

```
:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : A
 required: ?{val x: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method any2ArrowAssoc in object Predef of type [A](x: A)ArrowAssoc[A]
 and method any2Ensuring in object Predef of type [A](x: A)Ensuring[A]
 are possible conversion functions from A to ?{val x: ?}
       class A(x:Int) { println(x); def ==(a:A) : Boolean = { this.x == a.x; } }
                                                                        ^
```

This is scala 2.8 RC1.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to define the `equals(other:Any):Boolean` function, then Scala gives you `==` for free, defined as

```
class Any{
  final def == (that:Any):Boolean =
    if (null eq this) {null eq that} else {this equals that}
}
```

See chapter 28 (Object Equality) of Programming in Scala for more on how to write the `equals` function so that it's really an equivalence relation.

Moreover, the parameter `x` that you pass to your class isn't stored as a field. You need to change it to `class A(val x:Int)` ..., and then it will have an accessor that you can use to access `a.x` in the `equals` operator.

Comment: I suppose it's more accurate to say that it's not *accessible* as a field i.e. it doesn't generate accessor methods unless you declare it as a `val` when you pass it in.

Comment: Mm hmm. Alex may want to add `val` for other reasons, but someone could read your answer as implying that it's needed in order to access `x` in the body of `equals`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify that you need `val` to access `a.x` in the body of `equals`.

Comment: You can also do: `class A(private val x: Int)` if you don't want x to be visible as a field from outside the class.

Answer (score 7):

The error message is a little confusing because of coincidence with some code in Predef.  But what's really going on here is that you're trying to call the `x` method on your `A` class, but no method with that name is defined.

Try:

```
class A(val x: Int) { println(x); def ==(a: A): Boolean = { this.x == a.x } }
```

instead.  This syntax makes `x` a member of `A`, complete with the usual accessor method.

As Ken Bloom mentioned, however, it's a good idea to override `equals` instead of `==`.